# The way to describe the possession of an object being transferred multiple times?

Tags: expressions

Given a fact that:
My grandfather had a pen. He gave it to my father. My father gave it to me.

If I want to describe my pen based on this story, is it correct to say : "This is the pen my father gave me of his father." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual expression is that the pen was *[handed down](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handed%20down)* from your grandfather, to your father, to you.

> **handed down**, *tr. v.* : to transmit in succession (as from father to son)

Comment: If was not your grandfather to your father to you, you might want "This is the pen that B handed on to me from A".

Answer (score 0):

Formally, 'it has a long provenance' may be used.

> - This painting, with a long provenance in the family of the Earls of Denbigh, is thought to be a studio version from the original right
>   profile now in ...

[[Royal Museums ... Greenwich](https://www.rmg.co.uk/collections/objects/rmgc-object-14234)]

'Provenance' is a record of the history of ownership of an article, often broadened to the abstract history itself.